# Cannot delete VPC in aws eks cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cluster-computing, vpc, amazon-eks

I created an eks cluster on aws and try to deploy an app with loadbalancer then i tried to delete cluster and vpc but without delete any deployment and service in kubernetes so now i cannot delete vpc.

[image]
It always require to delete Network Interface but i cannot delete network interface.

AWS Document 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/delete-cluster.html

> Important
>
> If you have active services in your cluster that are associated with a
>   load balancer, you must delete those services before deleting the
>   cluster so that the load balancers are deleted properly. Otherwise,
>   you can have orphaned resources in your VPC that prevent you from
>   being able to delete the VPC.

so i would like to know how to force delete vpc?

Comment: Choose 'Force detachment' when trying to delete your ENI, but I would try to see what is attached to it in the first place that is preventing you from deleting it.

Comment: even i choose 'Force detachment'  but result is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after I deleted all the loadbalancers which are associated with apps in clusters and then i can delete VPC.

Additionally, ensure that all network assets with public interfaces (such as Internet Gateways, NAT Gateways, peering connections) are accounted for/removed before attempting to delete the VPC.